# Close pyplot and reopen with updated data from another thread

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-multithreading

I am trying to display a pyplot that updates every 3 seconds with data from another thread. I need to close the plot and reopen with the updated variables. I do not need an animation, I want to close the figure and open a new one.
This does not work unless I manually close the Figure window.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import threading as th
from time import sleep

Xplot = []
YPlot = []

def RandomXYGen():
    x = np.random.normal(5, .75)
    y = np.random.normal(10, 1.5)
    return x, y


def LoopData():
    while True:
        xdata, ydata = RandomXYGen()
        Xplot.append(xdata)
        YPlot.append(ydata)
        print(xdata, ydata)
        sleep(0.1)


def Plotter(xToPlot, yToPlot):
    plt.close('all')
    plt.plot(xToPlot, yToPlot)
    plt.show()

t = th.Thread(target=LoopData, daemon=True)
t.start()

while True:
    Plotter(Xplot, YPlot)
    sleep(3)
```

Any ideas why it is not closing?

[python 3.10.8 on Windows 10]

Comment: Use `plt.clf()` instead?

Comment: This does not work either. Plot does not update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts on figuring it out I was finally able to get help from the Python Discord server. This is what solves the above problem:

```
plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(0.01)
```

instead of:

```
plt.show()
```

Leaving this here in case someone runs into the same issue as me.